# stdafx.h and sapi.h not working correctly in C++ (using Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

So, I'm trying to make a personal assistant program for my desktop in C++. Basically, it opens up websites and programs on my computer for me. I was playing around with it and suddenly got the idea that it would be SO much cooler if it talked too. I found this  [Microsoft Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720163%28v=vs.85%29)  on how to do it, so I decided to give it a shot. I added in #include stdafx.h and #include sapi.h (I know it needs a less than and greater than sign, it wouldn't show up) on top of all my others, and added in the basic code into the main method to see if it would work. It didn't, giving me the compiler error that

```
fatal error: stdafx.h: No such file or directory
```

If I took stdafx.h out, it would just give me an error on sapi.h. Then I created a new project, and copied the code exactly from the website to see if it was my error, or something else. That didn't work either, so now I'm stumped. I'm relatively new to C++, but am pretty familiar with it. I'm running Windows 7 and using Code::Blocks to code. If this is a stupid problem and I'm missing some major problem, or I just messed something stupid up, cut me some slack. I'm not too good with errors. Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:
Also, I tried using quotations instead of a less than and greater than sign, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft tutorials assume you are using Visual Studio.  `stdafx.h` is created by the Visual Studio wizard as part of the precompiled header configuration.

You can probably replace

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

with

```
#include <windows.h>
```

plus the other stuff the tutorial said to put into `stdafx.h`.

Then you'll have to make sure the Windows SDK header directory is listed in your include path.  You did install the SDK, right?

Comment: I didn't even know about the windows sdk thanks. Ill try all that now.

Comment: Did it work? Please share your results so others can benefit too!